# does not contain a definition for 'Sum'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `using System.Linq;` so I am thinking my syntax has to be wrong but I can't see it

```
public void Count()
{
    var count = _context.Objects
        .Select(i => new { i, ViewCount = i.Relations.Sum(j => j.ViewCount) });
}
```

Comment: Do you need a .ToList() on i.Relations?

Comment: Are Relations an `IEnumerable<T>` or not? If it is not, then you can't use the `Sum` method or any other LINQ method.

Comment: If `i.Relations` doesn't have a method or extension named `Sum`, that very likely has something to do with the type of `i.Relations`. Do you think anybody here knows more about the type of `i.Relations` than you do? Or even as much?

Comment: What is the type of `Relations` property ?

Comment: That was the problem Relations was an object not an IEnumerable.  I'd like to mark an answer as correct ^.^ If someone would post it that would be awesome.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The members that `i.Relations` has are determined by the *type* of `i.Relations`. Since you included `using System.Linq;`, by far the most likely explanation is that `i.Relations` is declared as some type that doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. `i.Relations` could be all kinds of things, but it sounds like the compiler is telling you there's one thing it's not.

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely trying to sum string or any other object value collection.

Please try to convert the value before sum, you have to make sure j.ViewCount is always integer otherwise you'll got an exception. Please try the below code.

```
public void Count()
```

{
    var count = _context.Objects
        .Select(i => new { i, ViewCount = i.Relations.Sum(j => Convert.ToInt32(j.ViewCount)) });
}

Answer (score -3):

Relations property should be an IEnumerable. Be sure you have the

```
using System.Linq
```

sentence, because it is who brings the Sum extension method

Comment: That's the first line of the question